# Fireplace combustion air vent frozen

Tags: fireplace

I have a wood burning fireplace that has not been used for years (*and is not planning to be used*).

When it gets cold outside, the interior of the house near the fireplace also gets very cold. I was assuming the damper wasn't closing correctly or something, but then when I was feeling around I found this thing that literally had ice on the inside (*in the fire box*) of it. It's about 6" above the floor of the firebox.

I assume this is a fresh air intake?

Is there a way to seal this?

[image]

Comment: As an Alaskan i am legally bound to advise you to use Duct Tape. Can you get it, or any part of it, to turn? How high up is it, could you place one of those inflatable fireplace "pillows" below it to seal the entire flue?

Comment: @AlaskaMan I updated the question to indicate this thing is 6" from the floor of the firebox, so it's below any other place to seal instead.

Comment: yeah it looks like the cap might turn and in doing so seal the vent, you'll probably need to thaw it out first. (hairdryer, propane torch, light a fire, etc)

Comment: Ok, I'll wait until it isn't so cold and give it a try and get back to you :)

Comment: I found this https://youtu.be/EJzMRQwg-A0?t=189 which seems to 1) name the part and 2) show that mine is indeed already closed. So the question now is how to make it so that so much cold air is not getting in/"radiating" from this vent? You can see the ice is around the outside of the vent - would caulking around it help?